# How to change Filenet document MimeType using com.filenet.wcm.api

Tags: mime-types, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I am new to FileNet. We are using P8 Content Engine - 5.1.0.2
I need to change MimeType for existing document using Filenet WCM API. Workuround is to download the document, change the MimeType and re-upload the document but in this case the documnet Id will be changed. I prefer to update existing document instead of re-uploading the document.

Basically I need to do same thing that described in [Changing the content element MIME type](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/docsandfolders/df_change_content_mime.htm) programmatically throught Filenet WCM API.

the code is

```
public boolean changeDocumnetMimeType(String documentId, String docMimeType) throws IOException {

    com.filenet.wcm.api.TransportInputStream in1 = null;
    com.filenet.wcm.api.ObjectStore docObjectStore;
    com.filenet.wcm.api.Session session;

    try {

        session = ObjectFactory.getSession(this.applicationId, null, this.user,this.password);
        session.setRemoteServerUrl(this.remoteServerUrl);
        session.setRemoteServerUploadUrl(this.remoteServerUploadUrl);
        session.setRemoteServerDownloadUrl(this.remoteServerDownloadUrl);

        docObjectStore = ObjectFactory.getObjectStore(this.objectStoreName, session);
        Document doc = (Document) docObjectStore.getObject(BaseObject.TYPE_DOCUMENT, documentId);
        in1 = doc.getContent();
        System.out.println("documnet MIME type is : " + in1.getMimeType());
        //how to Update mimeType for the document???

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (in1 != null) {
        in1.close();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you are asking cannot be done.
Document objects are unable to update contentElements unless they are a reservation.  The MimeType (known as ContentType) is a property of the ContentTransfer object.   The ContentTransfer object is held in a ContentElementList.

Comment: @Christopher Powell  not sure that I understand your comment. it can't be done using Document object or can not be done through WCM API? the code is just test example that I tryed to implement for the task.

Comment: It doesn't matter which API you use, the FileNet system will not let a Document Object (or a sub-class of Document) alter content that has been Checked-In.
This is a Constraint on the (FileNet) Document Class.
Annotation Class however will allow changing of the Content without a reservation.
FileNet is structured much like an OOP language.  You create Document Objects based on the Document Class.

Comment: @ChristopherPowell so, the only option is to create new documnet with same content and new MimeType and remove old documnet?  Thank you

Comment: Yep.  You need a new reservation, so you will need to check out, replace content with different MimeType, check in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileNet is an EDMS system that structures it's records in a OOP fashion.

FileNet Document objects are instantiated from the FileNet Document Class.
Regardless of the API used, FileNet will not allow an update to occur on MimeType.
This is a constraint of the MimeType property.

[IBM FileNet MimeType Properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGLW6_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.prop.doc/props_Document.htm#MimeType)

The link above defines the MimeType property, and displays its contraints:
The key point here is : **Settability: SETTABLE_ONLY_BEFORE_CHECKIN**

This means that the MimeType property can only be set during the RESERVATION state of a Versionable object.  Non-Versionable objects (like Annotations) are not able to have this constraint.

Comment: Simply put, that is not possible because versioning assumes the content of any persisted document version is read-only. And MIME-type is inherent attribute of content.

PS "FileNet" is not a system. It was the name of the company acquired by IBM.